# IOS/Android Game programming

Tags: opengl-es

I am somewhat new to the whole game programming thing. I was wondering if I could develop a game for IOS and Android with using openGLES. if so how can I run the code on the devices and what are some good resources to continue learning from. I am only targeting mobile devices so information for PC/Mac is irrelevant to me. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resource you can look at on how to develop in OpenGL ES. I just linked iOS tutorial. The IDE you can get is Xcode to develop the game which has a way to test it out. Sadly with iOS, you cant actually have it tested on a device but for android you may test it without it being published in their Play store.

[Tutorial on how to get started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0)

[More resources](https://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/glkit)

Answer (score -1):

I think you would use the Android Studio for Android and Xcode for iOS. One more thing is the ShaderDesigner app (for Windows) it helps a lot on the development of shaders for you game or grphical application. I never programmed for iOS, so I don't know well what to do. But for Android, its amazing for learning from learnopengles. I think it's not complete, but if you're noob in GLES, this is good for now. After learning all they have there, you can search books in [it-eboos.info](http://it-ebooks.info)

Comment: Do I have to write my app once for IOS and once for android, or is there some way to port between

Comment: The shaders, no, but the code have to be adapted, it's not hard, just do some change in Android an then do in iOS, it will boost your job. Or, call someone to work with you like a partner.

Comment: thx for the input